# Android race condition: LinearLayout visibility is surviving next invocation of bindView()

Tags: android, android-layout, android-adapter

This is unbelievable to me but it seems I have a race condition in my List View item's adapter code. *Sometimes*, when I set one of the `LinearLayout` elements in my layout's visibility to `View.GONE` the next one is also is GONE. even though the value from the `Cursor` doesn't allow the code that does the `setVisibility()` to be invoked.

In my layout file for the list items I have:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pr_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    ...STUFF...

</LinearLayout>
```

The `bindView()` of my Adapter class that fills in the layout's values from my `Cursor` looks like so:

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    // stuff

    int foo = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("foo"));

    if (foo >= 10) {
        Log.e("bindView()", "Yes, the value is big enough to be doing this.");
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pr_linear_layout);
        ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

}
```

But as I scroll wildly up and down the list the items have randomly different visibilities for the LinearLayout in question!  The log message shows only the correct number of times and all of the other values in the layout are populated correctly.

Anyone ever see this before?

Comment: 1. Why are you overriding `bindView()` rather than `getView()`? 2. Why are you changing the visibility? 3. Are you familiar with view recycling?

Comment: (1) because that's how I've done it before and it's worked very well and seemed elegant! (2) because that's what the design I'm implementing calls for. The ListItem is three LinearLayouts and one of them needs to no be there when a certain condition occurs (3) I do believe so but your tone suggests I should look into it a bit more. In any case I solved the problem by explicitly setting the visibility to VISIBILE when the condition doesn't exist.

Comment: 1. I suggest you look at `getView()`. It essentially allows you to combine the logic of `newView()` and `bindView()` into a single method. 2. That seems reasonable. 3. I think I misunderstood exactly what you were doing. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: @PhilippeLePoint Do you have get answer ? i have same problem